# Can't get google maps to work with requirejs

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, requirejs, semantic-ui

I am quite new to require js, I have tried everything one could possibly find on google regarding google maps and require js. Everything else is ok on my page but google map, if I refresh the page google map shows up fine but when navigating through pages it won't.

Here's my **main.js**

```
require(['jquery','semantic','gmap'],function($,sm,gmap){
function initGMap(){
        console.log('Initiating google maps');
        //please ignore 'Info' 
        var myMap = new gmap.Map(document.getElementById('gmap-canvas'),{
                center: new gmap.LatLng(Info.lat, Info.lon),
                zoom: 15,
                mapTypeId: gmap.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var infowindow = new gmap.InfoWindow({
            content: Info.contStr
        });

        var marker = new gmap.Marker({
           position: new gmap.LatLng(Info.lat, Info.lon),
           map: myMap,
           title: 'My Title',

        });

        infowindow.open(myMap, marker);

        gmap.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.open(myMap,marker);
        });

        $('#gmap-canvas').on('load',function(){
            gmap.event.trigger(myMap, 'resize');
            map.setZoom( myMap.getZoom() );
        })

    }
    gmap.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initGMap);
    $(document).bind("projectLoadComplete",  initGMap);
```

});

This is what my **gmap.js** looks like

```
define('gmap',['async!https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY'],function(){
return window.google.maps;})
```

There isn't any other script file on the page than requirejs itself using the basic script tag like

```
<script data-main="scripts/main" type="text/JavaScript" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

**Note:** I am using semantic-ui though if that makes any difference

**ANY SUGGESTIONS WILL BE APPRECIATED!!**

Comment: I have a feeling that the require needs a nested define of gmap. If you do `console.log(gmap)` as the first line of your `require`, does it come out as `undefined` or do you get the object ?

Comment: it shows `undefined` but not everytime i load, pretty much every alternate load

Answer (score 0):

`google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initGMap);` is the culprit in my case. The event `'load'` isn't fired even after the page is finished loading so instead of using this statement I called `initGMap()` inside `$(document).ready()`.

Complete solution for this case

new **gmap.js**

```
define('gmap',['async!https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY'],function(){

    self.mapStart = function(){


            console.log('Initiating google maps');


            var myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap-canvas'),{
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(Info.lat, Info.lon),
                    zoom: 15,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: Info.contStr
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(Info.lat, Info.lon),
               map: myMap,
               title: 'My title',

            });

            infowindow.open(myMap, marker);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              infowindow.open(myMap,marker);
            });

    }

    return self;    
})
```

**main.js**

```
require(['gmap','jquery','semantic'],function(gmap,$,sm){


$(document).ready(function(){
       gmap.mapStart();
    });

});
```